# Detect keys in vbs/batch and encrypt them

Tags: batch-file, encryption, vbscript, background-process

Goal: Live encryption

Code: Vbs & batch (anything that windows can run without external programs).

Meaning: Detect keys and change them.

Example: You type: 'Hello world', then vbs replaces that with '-8208-6840-10032-10032-11400 -15048-11400-12768-10032-6384' (for example).

Problem: I do not want to use `Code = InputBox ("Code:")`, or in any way be in the program. The idea is the vbs file runs in the background.

Comment: You're free to believe whatever you like, but what you want still isn't possible in VBScript or batch.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Vbs and batch programs, if they interact with the user (via the keyboard) will run in the foreground. So when you say "runs in the background" it's not clear what you're thinking. Another way of clarifying is to explain what happens to the "encrypted" key strokes. Are they supposed to go to whatever program happens to be in the foreground? Or will they go to a specific program (that's supposed to be in the foreground while your script runs)? Or will the script consume the encrypted characters itself (in which case it might as well be in the foreground).

Comment: @user2460798 Vbs can run in the background and constantly send keys. by doing `set Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` and `WshShell.SendKeys "a"` If you'd loop that infinitely, every 10th of a second without returning anything, vbs will run in the background and whenever you can type, `a` will be returned.
The program would be like @DennisvanGils created, but without the shell. (You'd be in a word document and instead of a single 'a' press it will be '5h' for example.)

Comment: Yes you could send chars from Vbs in the background, but you couldn't receive input. The only ways I know of to receive keystrokes for a program in the background is to use a filter driver (with a private interface) or a global Windows hook - both of which I could supply more info on if they were applicable.

Comment: You didn't answer the question I posed. What's supposed to happen with the encrypted keystrokes?

Comment: @user2460798 They should end up in the place where your cursor is, in other words, the place where `WshShell.SendKeys "encryptionhere"` would end up. This means that there wouldn't be an output when you can't type. Example: you can't type while in a powerpoint presentation.

Comment: I think what @user2460798 means is what happens to the keys the program receives? If I am in a textbox and type a, should a be consumed, and not typed into the textbox? Should a go to another specified program?

Comment: @DennisvanGils It should be consumed and replaced with the encrypted version of the character, like your batch program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some thinking, and I came up with this. Far from perfect ofcourse, but it kind of works. It encrypts by using a choice with all letters from the alfabet, and stops when you press 1.

**Pros**:

- Pure batch, can run on any windows computer
- You can specify your own salt string
- Doesn't show just typed character, safe for use in public
- You can make the user set his own salt string with `set /P`, as well as the two 11s but you would have to make sure the user inputs are valid

**Cons**:

- Only accepts letters, doesn't accept spaces/numbers/special signs
- Need salt string to decrypt

Here is the code behind it:

```
@echo off
set saltString="ijklmaopqwxybcrstufghvdenz"
set "encryptionString="
:choiceLoop
cls
echo press 1 to stop
choice /C %saltString%1 /N /M %encryptionString%-
set keyCode=%errorlevel%
if %keyCode% GEQ 27 GOTO breakLoop
::encryption logic here
set /A keyCode=%keyCode%+11*11
echo %keyCode%
set encryptionString=%encryptionString%-%keyCode%
goto choiceLoop
:breakLoop
set encryptionString=%encryptionString%-
echo encrypted string: %encryptionString%
pause
```

Note that the salt string has to contain exactly 26 letters. You can change the encryption logic by changing the two 11s in the `set /A command`.

This first creates a variable, encryptionString, and the saltString. It than uses the choice command with the saltstring+1 as /C parameter, which is the characters to choose from. It uses /M (message) to show you what you've typed so far.

A thing to note about how you use the choice command is that it sets the errorlevel, to the position of the character you just typed in the /C parameter. This makes sure you can have assign differenct numbers to different characters, in this case i=1, j=2, k=3, l=4, m=5, a=6... (note that backspace and space, like for instance ., are invalid characters for the choice command)

It than multiplies the value of the errorlevel (which is saved in keyCode) with 11, and adds 11. After that it just adds the value of keyCode to the encryptionString. If the choice command returns 27 as errorlevel (1 is pressed), the loop is broken and the trailing - is added to the encryptionString.

Comment: Based on his example, I was under the impression he was looking for a simple substitution cipher, which would be extremely easy to do in batch (and probably VBScript, but my VBScript is pretty rusty).

Comment: @Dennis van Gils This is pretty genious. I have no clue what you are doing tho but that is on me. Would you mind taking the time to write what cmd does after every rule?
Also, is it possible to implement backspace and space? Because if that'd be possible the program would be pretty cool.

Comment: Updated my answer with an explanation. If you feel like my answer solved your problem, you can click the check to the left of it to mark it as correct.